# Make Icons Smaller with CSS on Mobile Screens Only Avada Fusion Page Builder

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I would like to make these icons (only these two icons, not any others on the page) smaller on mobile screens only using CSS. The site is on WordPress with Avada theme and Fusion Page Builder. https://cellboosteronline.com/pro-cell-mobile/

[Icons in COMPARE section of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCrMp.png)

Comment: Use media queries and add new value to font-size, width, height and line-height icon properties.

Comment: Specify class or id to target icons you want, then apply media queries on them.

Comment: As i said, specify a custom class or id to target icons you want only. For example, add responsive-icon class, and bind media queries on it.

Comment: This isn't working for me @media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
.fontawesome-icon.fa-trophy.fas.circle-yes {
font-size: 25px;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
line-height: 25px;
}
}